# Modifying query with additional parameters

Tags: mysql

I have a query with certain conditions:

```
SELECT...
FROM ...
WHERE unit = ".$unitID."
AND DATE(eventDate) = '".$myDate."'
AND IF ('".$myDate."' = '".$currentDate ."',
        eventTime < '".$currentTime ."',
        true)
```

Basically it looks for details on specific date, and if the date happens to be today, make sure the time for the event already passed.

I need to add additional parameters. If event is 'cancelled' or 'rescheduled', even if it is today and the time has not passed yet, grab those results as well.

```
AND IF (eventStatus = 'cancelled' OR offers_sent.rescheduled= 'rescheduled')
```

Having difficulty combining the two.

```
SELECT...
FROM ...
WHERE unit = ".$unitID."
AND DATE(eventDate) = '".$myDate."'
AND IF (
        ('".$myDate."' = '".$currentDate ."',
        eventTime < '".$currentTime ."',
        true)
        OR
        (eventStatus = 'cancelled' OR offers_sent.rescheduled= 'rescheduled')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
SELECT...
FROM ...
WHERE unit = ".$unitID."
AND DATE(eventDate) = '".$myDate."'
AND (IF ('".$myDate."' = '".$currentDate ."',
        eventTime < '".$currentTime ."',
        true)
    OR eventStatus = 'cancelled' OR offers_sent.rescheduled= 'rescheduled')
```

However, the condition in the if() function could be made in the calling application (php code?) and based on the outcome, you could simplify the sql you send to the database.

Comment: Ah... I was so close... You nailed it! Thanks.